# Is it possible for a root user to watch others' shell session secretly in live?

Tags: linux, bash, security, terminal, shell

I see a similar question on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353253/linux-terminal-how-to-capture-or-watch-other-terminal-session

Someone recommends [conspy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/conspy). However, it seems that conspy doesn't work for pts terminal.

I also tried the way to use `strace` to get the keys pressed [here](http://www.edwiget.name/2013/06/how-to-monitor-a-linux-users-shell-in-real-time/#codesyntax_1), but I found the result quite difficult to read.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Have you tried any of the other suggested answers on that link SO question?  There are several different ideas/approaches suggested.  Which have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: @techie007 tried every answer in the SO questions, but almost none works. The `cat /dev/pts/xx` works, but it will make the user's shell behave wierdly

Answer (score 5):

This works (kinda) for me:

```
tty=pts/0
sudo peekfd -8cnd $(ps -fat | grep "$tty *Ss" | awk '{print$1}') 0 1 2
```

Replace `pts/0` with the TTY of the user you want to watch. This will NOT work perfectly for everything, but it works with most input/output.

Answer (score 0):

ttysnoop is what you're looking for. It's been years since I've used it, so I'm not sure it works on modern kernels. You'll have to do some research to get it working. But if you do, please let me know.